On Hurwitz's Theorem (Complex Analysis)
In Functions of One Complex Variable by John B. Conway, Hurwitz's Theorem is stated as follows:

Let $G$ be a domain and suppose $(f_n)$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions which converges locally uniformly to $f$. If $f\not\equiv 0$, $\bar{B}(a,R) \subset G$, and $f(z) \neq 0$ for $z\in\partial B(a,R)$, then there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $f$ and $f_n$ have the same number of zeros in $B(a,R)$.

If I understand it correctly, $f\not\equiv 0$ means $f$ is not the constant function which is identically equal to $0$. That is, there is at least one point $w\in G$ where $f$ is nonzero. But if we further assume $f$ does not vanish on the boundary of the disk $B(a,R)$, that means $f\not\equiv 0$, so I do not understand why the author includes the seemingly redundant assumption $f\not\equiv 0$. Can anyone clarify this?

You are right. $f\not\equiv 0$ is redundant.

The statement here, while correct and useful in many situations does not quite capture the essence of Hurwitz which is that if $f_n \to f$ locally uniformly on a domain and $f$ not identically zero there ($f_n$ hence $f$ holomorphic) then every zero of $f$ inside the domain comes from zeroes of $f_n$ for $n$ large enough; note that $f$ can be continuous and vanish at a boundary point but that zero may or may not come from zeroes of $f_n$ and similarly $f$ can have infinitely many zeroes inside the domain (accumulating at boundary), both precluded in the statement above which is less general

So the condition $f$ not identically zero is crucial in the general form of Hurwitz but indeed redundant in the limited form here; an easy example not covered here is: take a unit disc function with infinitely many zeroes (eg infinite Blaschke product) and its Taylor polynomials which converge normally to it; being polynomials they have finitely many zeroes but still every zero of $f$ comes from zeroes of the polynomials just that the index when it starts to be approximated goes to infinity as the zero goes to the boundary

@Conrad Very informative. Thank you.
